# Как наиболее эффективно определить пересекаются ли два интервала (чисел или дат)?

Tags: любой-язык

Имеются 2 отрезка [x1; x2] и [y1; y2], как наиболее эффективно определить что они пересекаются?

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/325933/6766879

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3269434/6766879

Comment: вроде как ассоциация только один к одному работает

Comment: @Grundy, а она вообще работает? Ее и запускать, наверное, некому?

Comment: Ну вообще любой сотрудник может :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x1 <= y2 && y1 <= x2
```

Доказательство:

Пусть `A = Отрезок [x1; x2] расположен полностью левее отрезка [y1; y2] = x2 < y1`

Пусть `B = Отрезок [x1; x2] расположен полностью правее отрезка [y1; y2] = x1 > y2`

Тогда `C = Отрезки пересекаются = !A & !B = x2 >= y1 && x1 <= y2`, что и требовалось доказать.

Comment: считается ли пересечением касание? когда `x2 == y1`

Comment: можно добавить что это работает только для случая, когда координаты отсортированы

Comment: Да, считается, пересечение — это когда есть хотя бы одна общая точка. Ну, по крайней мере, в моем случае, если кому-то надо по другому, то поправить несложно